# Cartesian Product of the Real line with a discrete sets

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

Suppose $S$ is a set of n points, that is $|S| =n$ seen as a discrete smooth manifold. Then is the cartesian product of manifolds $\mathbb{R} \times S \simeq
\mathbb{R}^n$? If not what is it?

Comment: Is it possible to have a *discrete smooth manifold*?  If it is discrete, how can it be smooth?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\mathbb R\times S$ is homeomorphic to a disjoint union of $|S|$ copies of $\mathbb R$. This is not the same as $\mathbb R^n$, unless $n=1$. The space $\mathbb R\times S$ is a $1$-dimensional manifold, whereas $\mathbb R^n$ is $n$-dimensional. Also $\mathbb R\times S$  is disconnected, for $|S|>1$, whereas $\mathbb R^n$ is connected.

Comment: Ok. But what is the disjoint union of lets say two copies of $\mathbb{R}$ ? Is there a 'usual' manifold diffeomorphic to it?

Comment: @MarkNeuhaus The disjoint union of two copies of $\mathbb R$ *is* a 'usual' manifold as far as I'm concerned. It's essentially just two disjoint lines.

Comment: But this is diffeomorph to $\mathbb{R}$ itself, isn't it?

Comment: @MarkNeuhas: No. If you have two disjoint lines, there is no path that leads continuously from one to the other. So this space is not "path-connected." One line is, on the other hand, path-connected. Diffeomorphisms (and actually more generally homeomorphisms) preserve the property of path-connectivity.